# Execute command multiple times

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I don't have much knowledge of shell scripting. I have a command which is used multiple times but value is modifying.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tab=" --tab-with-profile=Default"
options=(--tab --title=Terminal)

cmd[1]="ping 192.168.9.10"
title[1]="10"

cmd[2]="ping 192.168.9.20"
title[2]="20"

cmd[3]="ping 192.168.9.30"
title[3]="30"

cmd[4]="ping 192.168.9.23"
title[4]="23"

cmd[5]="ping 192.168.9.26"
title[5]="26"

cmd[6]="ping 192.168.9.40"
title[6]="40"

cmd[7]="ping 192.168.9.41"
title[7]="41"

cmd[8]="ping 192.168.9.42"
title[8]="42"

cmd[9]="ping 192.168.0.43"
title[9]="43"

cmd[10]="ping 192.168.9.50"
title[10]="50"

cmd[11]="ping 192.168.9.11"
title[11]="11"

cmd[12]="ping 192.168.9.12"
title[12]="12"

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12; do
  options+=($tab --title="${title[i]}"  -e "bash -c \"${cmd[i]} ; bash\"" )          
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"


exit 0
```

I don't want to write `cmd[i]` and `title[i]`for multiple times. I want to write one single command that execute it multiple times.I don't know how to use `for` or `while` loop and execute a single command for different process rather multiple times.

Comment: Your IPs don't really follow a pattern (there's `9.23`, and `9.41` and `0.43` and a bunch of other IPs). If you can't find a pattern, you'll have to list the IPs, or at least the differing parts (for example, you could get away with only `9.23`, `9.41`, etc., and add `ping 192.168` in the loop.

Comment: A little off topic, you can do `for i in {1..12}` instead of what you wrote there :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your code a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

tab=" --tab-with-profile=Default"
options=(--tab --title=Terminal)

for i in 9.10 9.20 9.30 9.23 9.26 9.40 9.41 9.42 0.43 9.50 9.11 9.12; do
  options+=($tab --title=$i -e "bash -c 'ping 192.168.$i; bash'" )          
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"
```

This will set the titles to be `9.10`, `9.20`, etc. If you just want the part after `.`, you could use `--title=${i##*.}` instead of just `--title=$i`.

Comment: I was so simple. I just need to use `'ping 192.168.$i'` in place `\"${cmd[i]}`.  I modified it a little bit.. It's working if i use `10` only instead `9.10` and `ping 192.168.9.$i` but i still cannot generate an error.

Comment: @D'Duck Since it's getting complicate, you should consider writing another script, which takes the IP as an argument, runs `ping`, checks `ping`'s exit status and sends the mail, then call that script instead of `ping` here.

Comment: ok. I'll see then.